# Как перебрать всех детей игрового объекта Unity

Tags: unity3d

[image]

Изучаю Unity неделю

Первоначально стоит задача: каждые 2 секунды спавнить одну монетку на каждом споте поочередно.

*То есть 2 сек - спавним в первой точке. 4 сек - во второй точке, 6 сек - в третьей точке.*

Я хочу в массив `_points` поместить всех детей игрового объекта `Path` (см. скриншот), чтобы потом через обращение по индексу вызывать метод `CreateEnemy`. Но происходит конфликт, у массива тип `SpawnEnemy[]`, а у `_path.transform.GetChild(i)`тип данных `Transform`

***Собственно вопрос, как я могу поместить всех детей в этот массив?***

скрипт `ChoosePoint` (будет висеть на объекте `Path`):

```
    private SpawnEnemy[] _points;
    private GameObject _path;

    private void Start()
    {
        _points = new SpawnEnemy[_path.transform.childCount];
        for (int i = 0; i < _path.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
           _points[i] = _path.transform.GetChild(i); //  <---- Смотреть сюда
        }
    }
```

скрипт `SpawnEnemy` (будет висеть на каждом `Point`):

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject _template; // здесь будет монетка
private Vector3 _pointPosition;

private void Start()
{
    _pointPosition = GetComponent<Transform>().position;
}

public void CreateEnemy()
{
    GameObject newObject = Instantiate(_template, _pointPosition, Quaternion.identity);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private SpawnEnemy[] _points;
private GameObject _path;

private void Start()
{
    _points = _path.GetComponentsInChildren<SpawnEnemy>();
}
```

Comment: компонент Transform доступен только для чтения. И мне его не нужно менять, мне надо чтобы в _points у меня просто были все мои объекты (поинты) и потом через индекс я мог у этих точек вызывать CreateEnemy

Comment: Тогда вот так...

Comment: так работает, спасибо

Comment: В этом случае вы самостоятельно переиберайте все дочернии объекты и получайте у каждого SpawnEnemy, а в моём случаи это делается с помощью движка. Методы GetComponent и GetComponentsInChildren работает на стороне C++, а вызов из C# в C++ это потрея производительности, поэтому если у Вас 10 объектов в Path то будет 10 вызовов в C++, а GetComponentsInChildren только 1.

Comment: Но потери не большие, главное преимущество вы пишите меньше кода.

Comment: это вы о вашем ответе?  То что цикл не нужен, можно в 1 строчку сделать?

Comment: Да, и ответ на Ваш вопрос про GetComponent

Comment: _points = _path.GetComponentsInChildren<SpawnEnemy>();  Правильно я понимаю, что в этот массив у нас упадут все дочерние объекты у которых есть SpawnEnemy?

Comment: Да, метод GetComponentsInChildren сам выделит память для массива и туда положит все  дочернии объекты у которых есть SpawnEnemy

Comment: То есть <SpawnEnemy> это у нас грубо говоря фильтр для поиска? Ищем только те объекты у которых есть такой компонент?

Comment: И GetComponentsInChildren это не аналогично тому, если бы я эти объекты переносил явно в инспектор?

Comment: Да, эта фильтрация сделана с помощью общих методов https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods

Comment: Да, не аналогично